# c++ template for constant data holder class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr

I am trying to design a class which all its data is constant and know at compile time. I could just create this by manually typing it all but I want to use a template so that I don't have to rewrite almost the same code many times.

I was thinking templates are the way to do this e.g

```
template<class T> class A { ... }

A<float>
A<MyObject>
A<int>
```

But then I wasn't sure how I could get the constant data that I know into this object. I could do it at run-time with a member function which does a switch statement on the type or something similar but I ideally want it to effectively be a dumb data holder for me to use.

So in the case of `A<float>` I would have this:

```
// member function
int getSize() {
    return 4;
}
```

Instead of (pseudo code)

```
// member function
int getSize() {
    if (type == float) {
        return 4;
    } else if ...
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a known way to do this? I don't have any experience with constexpr, could that be the key to this?

**edit:** To clarify: I want member functions which always return the same result based on the templated type/class. For example, A would always return 4 from getSize() and 1 from getSomethingElse() and 6.2 from getAnotherThing(). Where as A would return 8 from getSize() and 2 from getSomethingElse() and 8.4 from getAnotherThing().

Comment: did you try [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)?

Comment: Are you reimplementing `sizeof`?

Comment: What should this template do that `const double x = 0.75;` doesn't?

Comment: @LogicStuff No, I see that getSize is now a bad example but there are other methods the object would have only meaningful to me.

Comment: or [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)?

Comment: @n.m. This template isn't actually assignable like that it is to hold meta data about a certain type/class.

Comment: @torkleyy I will look into template specialization, that could be part of the answer.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Are you asking to have a templated constant? Do you want instead to have a member function that always returns the same value? What do you mean by "a class which all its data is constant and know at compile time"?

Comment: @Omnifarious Yes, I want member functions which always return the same result based on the templated type/class. For example, `A<float>` would always return 4 from getSize() and 1 from getSomethingElse() and 6.2 from getAnotherThing(). Where as `A<MyObject>` would return 8 from getSize() and 2 from getSomethingElse() and 8.4 from getAnotherThing().

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that. It is still not clear what your exact problem is. Why `A<T>::getSize()` is better than `sizeof(T)`?

Comment: @n.m. it isn't just getSize() I need, there is other 'meta data' I need to hold which can't be done with c++ features like sizeof, they are numbers that mean only stuff to me.

Comment: Sound like type traits

Comment: @LYF_HKN type traits but my own traits.

Comment: @TomShar Like this? http://ideone.com/aWNfVZ (This class provides the appropriate specifiers to use with printf)

Comment: @LYF_HKN that would hit my needs but I think. But I think another answer might be better for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this template

```
template <int size_, int foo_, int bar_>
struct MyConstData {
   static const int size = size_; // etc
};
```

Then specialize your template:

```
template <class T> class A;
template <> class A<float> : MyConstData<13,42,-1> {};
template <> class A<double> : MyConstData<0,0,42> {};
```

Comment: But, what if you want the templated implementation that was declared in your original definition for class A for all the other member functions for your specialized templates?

Comment: If the OP really is just doing type traits style classes, I like this the best.

Comment: @Omnifarious It is my understanding that OP is asking how to define A, not what to do with already-defined A. If you want a default implementation in an unspecialised A, just provide a definition for it.

Comment: I will play around with this but I think this is exactly what I need, i'll let you know shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can specialize particular functions within a class, and given your description of things, I suspect that's what you want. Here is an example of how this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class A {
 public:
   int MyConstantFunction() const { // Default implementation
      return 0;
   }
};

template <>
int A<int>::MyConstantFunction() const
{
   return 3;
}

template <>
int A<float>::MyConstantFunction() const
{
   return 5; // If you examine the world, you'll find that 5's are everywhere.
}

template <>
int A<double>::MyConstantFunction() const
{
   return -5;
}

int main(int, char *[])
{
   using ::std::cout;
   A<int> aint;
   A<float> afloat;
   A<long> along;

   cout << "aint.MyConstantFunction() == " << aint.MyConstantFunction() << '\n';
   cout << "afloat.MyConstantFunction() == "
        << afloat.MyConstantFunction() << '\n';
   cout << "along.MyConstantFunction() == "
        << along.MyConstantFunction() << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Notice how `along` just used the default implementation from the class declaration. And this highlights a danger here. If the translation unit using your specialization for a given type hasn't seen that specialization, it won't use it, and that may cause all kinds of interesting problems. Make sure this happens.

The other option is to not provide a default implementation at all, and so you get an instantiation error.

My gut feeling is that you are doing something that is pointless and a poor design. But, since I don't know the full context I can't say that for sure. If you insist on doing this, here's how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement different things depending on the type, you could try this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
    T data;

    string toString() {
         return myGeneralToString(data);
    }
};

template <>
class Foo<string> {
    string data;

    string toString() {
        return "Already a string: " + data;
    }
};
```

If you just want templated constants, I'd try this:

```
template <int a, int b>
class Calc {
public:
    static constexpr int SUM = a + b;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Calc<3, 5>::SUM << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: as pointed out by Omnifarious C++14 has templated constants without templating the class itself. So you could simplify the example to:

```
class Calc {
public:
    template <int a, int b>
    static constexpr int SUM = a + b;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Calc::SUM<3, 5> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TomShar Does this help you or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: C++14 has actual templated constants. You would write that `template <int a, int b> constexpr int CalcSum = a + b;` in idiomatic C++14.

Comment: @Omnifarious ah I didn't know that. I'll add it to the answer